# What is wrong in my backpropagation? (Java)

Tags: java, machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation, perceptron

```
protected List<Double> weight;
protected List<ABPPerceptron> next;
protected List<ABPPerceptron> prev;
protected Double bias;
protected Double w0;
protected Double theta;
protected Double net;
protected Double out;
protected Double upgrade;

public ABPPerceptron(int k, Double bias, Double theta) {
    if (bias == 0D)
        System.out.println("bias must be not 0!!");

    this.theta = theta;
    this.bias = bias;
    weight = new ArrayList<>();
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        weight.add(rand.nextDouble());
    }
    w0 = rand.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("weights: " + w0 + " " + Arrays.toString(weight.toArray()));
}

public void calculate() {
    net = bias * w0;
    for (int i = 0; i < prev.size(); i++) {
        net += prev.get(i).getOut() * weight.get(i);
    }
    out = evaluate(net);
}

public void outLayerLearn(Double expected) {
    upgrade = (expected - out) * derivate(out);

    w0 += theta * upgrade * bias;
    for (int i = 0; i < weight.size(); i++) {
        weight.set(i, weight.get(i) + (theta * upgrade * prev.get(i).out));
    }
}

public void hiddenLayerLearn() {
    upgrade = 0D;
    int f = next.get(0).prev.indexOf(this);
    for (ABPPerceptron n : next) {
        upgrade += n.upgrade * n.weight.get(f);
    }
    upgrade *= derivate(out);
    w0 += theta * upgrade * bias;
    for (int i = 0; i < weight.size(); i++) {
        weight.set(i, weight.get(i) + (theta * upgrade * prev.get(i).out));
    }
}
```

this is part of my neuron class, the network call the `outLayerLearn` on all output neuron and the `hiddenLayerLearn` on others except the last, the input layer.
I always call the calculate before each ephoc.

My problem is I cant get the correct result after 10000 epochs.

The main looks like this after I set the `xor` inputs and outputs.
The `xor` has 2 input, 2 hidden and 1 output sigmoid neuron.

```
    int echo = 10000;
    for (int i = 0; i < echo; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < inputs.size(); j++) {
            xor.calculate(inputs.get(j));
            List<Double> e = new ArrayList<Double>();
            e.add(expected.get(j));
            xor.learn(inputs.get(j), e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's probably not the cause for the problem, but is there a specific reason why you're using `Double` instead of simply `double` in most places? Your code doesn't seem to consider `null` to be a meaningful value for those fields, so why allow it?

Comment: I just wanted to use `List` which needs `Object`

Comment: Sure, it makes sense to use it there, but why are `bias`, `w0`, `theta`, ... all `Double` as well? It's probably not a huge issue, but it's a little wasteful. And when you want to put one into a list a `double` will be auto-boxed into a `Double` anyway. In other words: outside of the type argument of something like `List<Double>` there is rarely a reason to use `Double` over `double`.